# Build Message object from previous object dump

Tags: python, telethon

In the Telethon library, is it possible to build a `Message` object from the JSON or dictionary representation of a message obtained with the `to_dict()` method?

I have several message dumps from which I'd like to download the associated media using `download_media()`. I tried to build the object using the Message constructor, but I always come across a `NotImplementedError` exception.

```
from telethon.tl.custom.message import Message
m = <message json>
message = Message(m)
print(message)
```

Comment: better show minimal working code which makes the same problem. With code we can run it and test problem